# wavelet decomposition and reconstruction in matlab

Tags: matlab, wavelet

By using the wavelet toolbox it becomes possible to decompose and reconstruct a time series, e.g.

```
load leleccum; 
s = leleccum(1:3920); 

% decomposition
[c,l] = wavedec(s,3,'db5');

% Reconstruction
a0 = waverec(c,l,'db5');
```

From this, how is it possible to remove specific frequencies from the series? For example, once I have decomposed the series into its frequency components, how can I remove a frequency such as a daily cycle from it prior to reconstruction?

Example of signal with 24 unit cycle:

```
t = 1:365;
raw =  20+(10-2).*rand(1,length(t)); 
signal_1 = 10*sin(2*pi*t/24); 

y = raw + signal_1; % example data series

% decomposition
[c,l] = wavedec(y,3,'db5');
```

How would you remove the signal with a periodicity of 24 i.e. 'signal_1' from the final series?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to modify the vectors`c` and `l` that you get from `wavedec`. If you want to remove certain frequencies, find the data corresponding to those frequencies and zero it out. Then call call `waverec` to reconstruct the modified time series.

Comment: thanks for your response. Although I understand the concept of removing certain frequencies and then reconstructing the array but when I use other packages for obtaining the wavelet coefficients it returns a matrix showing how each frequency varies in time. Therefore I am a bit confused as to why this command returns a vector i.e. not showing how similar frequencies varies in time, from 'c' I read this as showing all of the frequencies that make up the series, where none of the frequencies are repeated. Have I misunderstood its use?

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation for wavedec](http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wavedec.html) to learn about the `c` and `l` vectors.

Comment: I have read through the documentation but am still unsure about the wavelet decomposition vector 'c', I have added an example code in my original post, would you be able to show me with this example how the frequencies noted should be removed prior to reconstruction.

Comment: @user1155751 You have to figure out which parts of `c` and `l` correspond to your signal of interest. I don't have access to the wavelet toolbox so I don't think I can help any further.